# SSIS Variable Scope Issues

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, integration, etl

I'm trying to iterate over a few Excel files in a document using a foreach loop. So in my Control Flow I drag and drop a For Each Loop Container. I then create a new variable called ExcelFilePath and put it under the foreach loops scope:

[image]

I then edit the foreach loop and set it's variable mapping to map to the created variable:

[image]

Great. So now at this stage I'm assuming that with every iteration this foreach loop does, it's going to store the file path (or whatever) to the current excel file in that variable.

Next I insert a Data Flow Task and add an Excel Source. Initially I create an Excel connection manager, just to point to the correct sheet in the document and specify what columns I want. I test it and see that the preview works nicely.

[image]

Nice. So next I want to change the connection manager, so that it doesn't map to the same file the whole time, but instead uses the variable that the foreach loop sets, specifying what file to use. So I right click on the Excel Connection Manager > Properties, and add an expression. I choose 'ExcelFilePath' for the 'property' and I look for the ExcelFilePath variable that I created that will be in the foreach loops scope.. But nothing. Nowhere to be found.

[image]

What is it that I'm doing wrong here? I've followed various tutorials on the subject to the letter, yet on my side the foreach variable just is nowhere to be found??

**EDIT**

I then went ahead and changed the scope of the variable from the foreach loops scope to 'package' scope. And hey I can now see it, perfect. I select it and this happens:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Finally got that working, yet now I have yet *another* error:

[image]

I honestly don't know how anyone can get any work done using this. I take my hat off to you. I mean `Error Code 0x80004005`, what's *that* supposed to mean?!

Comment: Connection Manager is outside the scope of your loop container hence you cannot see the variable in expression builder

Comment: Thanks ughai. What would the solution then be in this case? How can I reference it?

Comment: It should be in Package scope

Comment: I think, it's because you clicked on evaluate expression without dragging the variable into the expression textbox (your error covers that part of the screenshot so not 100% if that is what you are doing).

Comment: The expression automatically gets evaualted right after I just drag it in. Finally got it working though. Have a look at EDIT 2, yet another error... @ughai .

Comment: Small input, for your Excel connection and your Data Flow set the Delay-Evaluation to True. And make sure your ExcelFilePath variable as a valid path while you are developing the package.

Comment: @mixx thanks for your input. However, Delay Evaluation is indeed set to true already on both my data flow and excel connection manager. The path is also a valid path.

Comment: Welcome to the happy world of SSIS development.  The excel connection probably needs an excel file to point at before the loop starts.  Make an excel template file with just the headers and point the connection at it.  Then set the connection expression to the variable and it should be happy.  Also, ensure "Validate External MetaData" is False.  Finally, Excel and SSIS don't play well together, despite being MS products.

Comment: When you get an OLEDB error, there are usually multiple error messages and one of them has the details of what the SQL error was.   Check the error messages tab.   if not, run a profile trace and see what the SQL is that generates the error.  Run it in SSMS to get a better error msg.

Comment: In the View menu, select Output (Ctrl+Alt+O) Look at the text there for lines that start with Error. That is how you can get the actual error message versus the less than helpful mouseover error message or the text from the Execution Results tab

Comment: I very much echo the Excel and SSIS not playing nice together.  Is there anyway you can change the files to .csv or .txt prior to starting up or in your package? Or better yet can you get them in that format.  Not sure what your working parameters are, but if you can feed them in via flat files your looping will work much better.

Comment: For SSIS, I set all varaibles to the scope of the entire package.  It saves tons of headaches.  And as others stated, you have to have a file to point at, even if its a dummty one.  Also, depending what you are doing, treating the Excel connection as an OLEDB may be a better answer.  For some projects that has worked well for me,

Comment: Could you provide more details on the Error? Error Code 0x80004005 means that something went wrong in AcquireConnection call, so SSIS was not even able to open your Excel file. More details are in the next lines of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we can not use variable for excel connection which will point data file on runtime changing because there are so many problems in Excel and SSIS.

So, you need to some thing like below.

Add one scrip task in for each loop container before data flow task.
Also create one template file with static location with same header which has file.

Now while iterating file by for each loop. The file we are processing for particular iteration need to replace template using script task.

Excel connection manager always point template file.

```
  what ever file name you getting by for each loop need to replace template
```